# Python error only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python

I'm writing a tKinter GUI and I've come accross a problem. Given the the main code is way to large, I've made a dummy example to replicate my problem.

```
class test():
    def __init__(self,time,a):
        
        self.time = time
        self.a = a
    
    def something(self):
        
        self.b = float(self.time) * self.a
        
        return {'bVar':self.b}

time = np.linspace(0,100,10)
testObj = test(time,2.2)
print(testObj.something().get('bVar'))
```

The error is:

```
----> 9         self.b = float(self.time) * self.a
     10 
     11         return {'bVar':self.b}

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

If I remove the float conversion of time, then it works. But in my main GUI I need to keep float(self.time).
self.a in my GUI is a tKinter entry that has to be also of type float(entry[1].get())

Any thoughts on how I can remedy this?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand why you need to keep `float(self.time)` if `self.a` is the different type of variable?

Comment: yes I need to keep float(self.time)

Comment: Why do you need `float(self.time)`? What do you expect the output of `float(np.linspace(0,100,10))` to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error "only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars" is raised when the function expects a single value but you pass an array instead.

Problem is that you are passing an array `self.time` to the `float` that expects a single value instead of an array.

You got `time` using np.linspace(0, 100, 10) which returns an array of evenly spaced numbers over a specified interval.

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html

**Updating my answer, assuming you want to multiply each value in the list with a single value.**

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self,time,a):
        self.time = time
        self.a = a
    
    def something(self):
        self.b = np.array(self.time, dtype=float) * self.a
        return {'bVar':self.b}

time = np.linspace(0,100,10)
testObj = Test(time,2.2)
print(testObj.something().get('bVar'))
```

You can set `dtype=float` in `numpy` array to set the data type of the array to `float`. And then you can use * to multiply a single value with each value in the array.

Comment: I understand, but is there a way around it?

Comment: @Adrian do you just want to multiply each value in the list with a single value?

Comment: @Adrian I have updated my answer, please upvote if it helps you with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a workaround

```
class test():
    def __init__(self,time, a):
        
        self.time = time
        self.a = a
    
    def something(self):
        
        self.b = float(self.time) * self.a
        self.c = float(self.time) * 10
        
        return {'bVar':self.b, 'cVar':self.c}

#time = np.linspace(0,100,10)
list1 = []
list2 = []
for time in range(0,1000):
    testObj = test(time, 2.2)
    list1.append(testObj.something().get('bVar'))
    list2.append(testObj.something().get('cVar'))
    
a = np.array([list1,list2])
a[0]
```